# Is there a way to get the "original" text data for OpenNLP?

Tags: java, nlp, opennlp

I know that this question was asked before - but the answer was not satisfying (in the sense of that the answer was just a link ).

So my question is, is there any way to extend the existing openNLP models? I already know about the technique with DBPedia/Wikipedia. But what if i just want to append some lines of text to improve the models - is there really no way? (If so - that would be really stupid...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27301800/appending-words-to-an-existing-opennlp-pos-database) which has a detailed answer to the same problem.

I think, that is a though problem because when you deal with texts you have often licensing issues. For example, you can not build a corpus on Twitter data and publish it to the community (see [this paper](http://epub.uni-regensburg.de/29468/1/GSCL-2013-Tworpus_pub_server.pdf) for some more information).

Therefore, often companies build domain specific corpora and use them internally. For example, we did in our research project. Therefore, we built a tool (Quick Pad Tagger) to create annotated corpora efficiently (see [here](http://airccj.org/CSCP/vol5/csit53513.pdf)).

Comment: Wow ok. Thanks for your help. That really sucks!!! openNLP would benefit a lot if more people train the modles!

Comment: I provided some additional information (see updated answer). I hope that it is helpful to you. Do you mind to mark the answer a correct?

Comment: Sure :) Forgot that. Thanks a lot for your help.
I'm working right now but i will have a detailed look at the links later!
Your F-Scores are impressive! Gj on that

Comment: I just realized that this is really awesome :) Is there a download link? I would like to try this tool

Comment: Ah - sry for posting so much -> definitely have a look at the yago databse. It is open source and i think that you can somehow use it to train the models

Comment: Can you write me an E-Mail (first author in the paper) and than wie can discuss how you can get the tool. I would really like to open source the tool but I do not have the permission yet.

Comment: @FabianLurz, FYI, you might want to check out [NLPf](https://gitlab.com/schrieveslaach/NLPf/).

Answer (score 1):

Ok i think this needs a separate answer.
I found the Yago database: http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/departments/databases-and-information-systems/research/yago-naga/yago//

This database seems to be just fantastic (from the first look). You can download all the tagged data and put it in a database (they already deliver the tools for that).

The next stage is to "refactor" the tagged entities so that opennlp can use it (openNLP uses sth. like this `<START:person> Pierre Vinken <END>`)

Then you create some text files and train it with the opennlp delivered training tool.

Not 100% sure if this works but i will come back and tell you.

Comment: Hey ! can you please elaborate how to use these data for training OpenNLP models?